# MS Access - Change appearance of form when using "Filter by Form"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have created a front and back-end database MS Access solution (I am limited to MS Access 2013) for my team, utilizing forms for data entry, lookup, and editing. It is working well, but every now and then a user will forget they are in "Filter by form", and enter data into the filter instead of the actual form. When they realize their mistake, they have to re-enter all of the data.

Is it possible to change the appearance of the form when you are in "Filter by Form"? For instance, change the background color, or add a text box notification so that it is very obvious to the user that they are in "Filter by Form"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Me.FilterOn` property to help determine whether the form filter (ie., `Home`→`Advanced`→`Filter By Form` ) is on.

You might need to play with it a bit but from my experiment, you could have something in the `OnOpen` event that checks the property and acts appropriately.

I believe the catch is that code won't execute when it's in Filter mode, so therefore, you'd have to make the default appearance the "Filter appearance" (perhaps add a Graphic or Textbox that says "Filter Mode"), and then if `Me.FilterOn = False` you can hide that label in the `OnOpen` event.

> ### [image: img] Also:
>
> The **Apply Filter** button indicates the state of the **`Filter`** and **`FilterOn`** properties. The button remains disabled until there is a filter to apply. If an existing filter is currently applied, the ***Apply Filter* button appears pressed in**.
>
> To apply a filter automatically when a form or report is opened, specify in the **`OnOpen`** event property setting of the form either a macro that uses the `ApplyFilter` action or an event procedure that uses the `ApplyFilter` method of the `DoCmd` object.
>   <sub>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/form-filteron-property-access))</sub>

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Apply a filter to view select records** (Form Filter)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-a-filter-to-view-select-records-in-an-access-database-2a493ded-e544-4144-9103-b9b1d1865147#formfilter)
- expertsexchange : [**Determine if filter is applied**](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26709394/determine-if-filter-applied-in-access-form.html)
- MSDN : [**Form.FilterOn Property** (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/form-filteron-property-access)